# Choosing Which Submit on Form via Keyboard (not just Enter)

Tags: html, forms, submit

I am interested in doing the following without anything other than HTML/CSS (& PHP server side)

I have a single Form with Multiple Submits let say S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6

I would like the user to be able to choose S1 by pressing 1 on the keyboard, S2 by pressing 2 etc.

As you might have guessed this is to help some smartphone users

Is this possible?

(I would like to avoid the using having to enter a digit in a textbox, then to Submit)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use accesskey attribute:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-accesskey

Comment: Hmmm I'm reading up about this but it requires ALT + key. Still reading to find out more... So still accepting other ideas...

Comment: No this solution is not going to work unfortunately. Two problems stick out aside from not being exactly what I wanted. Firstly it appears web mobile browsers are not great on accesskey support and activating the accesskeys is not always ALT or SHIFT. Secondly it would be hard to educate non-disabled users to utilize this feature even if I could guarantee knowing if their browser offeered it.

Comment: It looks like the only "plain HTML" solution, otherwise you need JavaScript.

Comment: I thought as much... wishful thinking. But not the end of the world to let javascript creep in for an optional extra...